# How should I upgrade an OS on an OPAL encrypted drive?

Tags: kubuntu, self-encrypting-drive, opal, tcg-opal, sedutil

I'm currently running Kubuntu 17.04 installed on a Samsung NVMe EVO 960 SSD drive.

I managed to install it with OPAL encryption enabled by using [sedutil](https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil), but it took me about 2 days to make it work (I had to compile the image by hand, since the binary provided by the project would not work for me).

Now I'd like to upgrade to Kubuntu 18.04 and I was thinking which is the best way to do it.

1. Is there a way to safely and correctly update to 18.04 *from **17.04*** without reinstalling the OS? This would probably be the mostplausible and  hassle free way to avoid re-setting up the OPAL disk, but I fear it will probably create issues with old settings.
2. Can I just decrypt my SSD, and stick a liveCD and boot from it and install Kubuntu as if it was a normal disk? Would this preserve the encryption and would the system boot up again correctly? I'd *love* to see this work.
3. Do I have to remove OPAL encryption, install the new Kubuntu and spend an other day recompiling a new OPAL image and activating the encryption on the SSD? I fear this will be the probable correct way of doing things...

I have already read all the documentation about sedutil but I didn't find anything about upgrading an OS, which I believe means that I simply have to disable OPAL encryption, perform the upgrade as usual and re-enable it, but I wanted to be sure if there are easier alternatives.

---

Obviously I'll backup all important information and user configuration from the old OS before trying this upgrade.

Comment: How about just boot the Kubuntu 17.04 and let it update itself? It can install new packages now, can't it? Or is it using some type of read-only filesystem?

Comment: @Xen2050 You cannot update directly from 17.04 to 18.04. In any case I'd like a more general answer too. If I wanted to install, say, CentOS instead of Ubuntu that possibilty is gone. I want to know: is there a way to avoid disabling OPAL encryption when reinstalling the OS?

Comment: Right, you have to stop at 17.10 first, but if it works it would solve your problem #1 directly. And do you need a special opal-built kernel all the time? How do you enter the passphrase when booting, doesn't the BIOS decrypt the drive, and therefore the OS too? If sedutil is just for managing/changing the drive's encryption, maybe you only need a opal-built kernel on a live USB/DVD for occasional use.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you think you would need to disable encryption during upgrade. You just unlock the drive in any suitable way (using PBA image or standalone `sedutil` binary) and proceed with upgrade.

It is also not clear why you think you would need to recompile anything. If by "OPAL image" you mean PBA image, then it doesn't depend on OS in any way.

In any case, disabling and enabling encryption is straightforward:

```
sedutil-cli --disableLockingRange 0 <Admin1Password> <device>
```

```
sedutil-cli --enableLockingRange 0 <Admin1Password> <device>
```